# Django-NVD3 - Cannot change line color

Tags: python, django, django-views, nvd3.js

I have multiple graphs on one page and I am unable to change the color of the lines no matter how I try to explicitly state it. I followed the official documentation and the colors do not change. https://github.com/areski/django-nvd3/blob/master/demoproject/demoproject/views.py#L275

```
extra_series1 = {"tooltip": {"y_start": "", "y_end": " Mbps"},
               "date_format": tooltip_date,
               'color': '#555555'}

chartdata = {
    'x': xdata,
    'name1': 'Requests Per Second', 'y1': ydata, 'extra1': extra_series1
}
```

I can however in extra:

```
    'extra': {
        'x_is_date': True,
        'x_axis_format': '%H:%M:%S',
        'tag_script_js': True,
        'jquery_on_ready': False,
        'color_category':'category10',
```

And graphs with multiple lines will have a color palette to graph from. However, I need different colors for 1 line graphs.

Based off what pip displays - I have the newest version.

django-nvd3==0.6.0

Comment: I am not sure how django-nvd3 works, but you can try passing an array of colors instead of `category10`

Comment: I did try this and every example on the update page. http://tinyurl.com/mzcnxe9 Not sure why I can't override any of this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know it's a very old topic, but I had the issue myself running:

```
django-nvd3==0.9.7
python-nvd3==0.14.2
```

If you take a look at the [python-nvd3 lineChart.py (line 27)](https://github.com/areski/python-nvd3/blob/v0.13.10/examples/lineChart.py#L27) code example, you'll see the color must be passed as keyword argument like so:

```
kwargs2 = {'color': 'red'}
chart.add_serie(y=ydata, x=xdata, name='sine', extra=extra_serie, **kwargs1)
```

Then if you take a look at
[django_nvd3/templatetags/nvd3_tags.py#L67](https://github.com/areski/django-nvd3/blob/v0.9.7/django_nvd3/templatetags/nvd3_tags.py#L67) source you can see the this same keyword argument is recreated from each series just like the "extra1" and "extra2" is created from [their demo_linechart](https://github.com/areski/django-nvd3/blob/v0.9.7/demoproject/demoproject/views.py#L71).
So if you want to have one line red and the other one blue you can do the following:

```
chartdata = {
    'x': xdata,
    # series 1
    'name1': 'series 1',
    'y1': ydata,
    'extra1': extra_serie1,
    'kwargs1': { 'color': 'red'}, # <- the important part
    # series 2
    'name2': 'series 1',
    'y2': ydata2,
    'extra2': extra_serie2,
    'kwargs2': { 'color': 'blue'}, # <- the important part
}
```

I'll probably create a pool request with the fix.

Edit: I've created a [pull request](https://github.com/areski/django-nvd3/pull/75) that fixes the code example.

Comment: Appreciate this response even years later. I still only have blue lined graphs implemented. What is the proper way to utilize color now since that pull request has been accepted? Even prior to updating my nvd3 (which I haven't done in a while) this still doesn't change the color to red. 

reqps_data = {
        'x': xdata,
        'name1': 'Requests Per Second', 'y1': ydata, 'extra1': req,
        'kwargs1': {'color': 'red'},
    }
   reqps_type = "lineChart"
   reqps_container = 'reqps_container'

Comment: @JohnZ The pull request only updated their misleading code example. The way they were changing color in the code example was not correct. Now it's fixed upstream in their code example, the same way it is in my answer. I've just double checked with django-nvd3==0.9.7 & python-nvd3==0.14.2, it works for me :S What you pasted in the comment looks correct now, but it's hard to say having just this little peace of code. You'll probably have to post a new clean question on Stackoverflow, I'm afraid :S